# Subset of ESet /dividing ESet

Tags: r, statistics, expression, bioconductor

Is it possible to subset a ExpressionSet like this:

> SUB=ESet[,ESet@phenoData@data$x==c(0,1)]

in X are values from 0-9, and I just want the entries when x=0 or x=1.

Comment: if you enter that in your console and you get the correct result, it is possible. Otherwise it is not.

Comment: Aargh, why are you accessing ESet in that way? use ESet$x.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
SUB=ESet[, ESet$x %in% c(0,1)]
```

At first glance, the difference between `==` and `%in%` seems only subtle.

```
x <- 0:9

x[x==c(0, 1)]
[1] 0 1

> x[x %in% c(0, 1)]
[1] 0 1
```

But `%in%` will never return `NA`, and this could be useful, or even essential, depending on what you want to do.  In the following constructed example, `==` returns `NA`, whilst `%in%` returns the expected result:

```
x <- c(NA, 0:9)

x[x==c(0, 1)]
[1] NA

x[x %in% c(0, 1)]
[1] 0 1
```

But the difference is much deeper than this.  From the help files for ?`==` it is apparent that when making binary comparisons between vectors of unequal length, the elements of shorter vectors are recycled as necessary.

Try for example the following:

```
x <- 0:9
x[x==c(1, 2)]
integer(0)
```

This results in an empty vector.  If you recycle the vector c(1, 2), it quickly becomes apparent why:

```
x:       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
c(1, 2): 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
'==':    F F F F F F F F F F
```

Comment: Thank you very much what is the difference between "==" and "%in%"?

Comment: @Azil : `==` compares elementwise, whereas `%in%` tells you whether or for the elements in the left hand side a match could be found in the right hand side. compare `1:2 == 4:1` and `1:2 %in% 4:1`. See also `help(Comparison)` and `help(match)` for more explanation.

Comment: @Azil I have expanded my answer to explain the difference.